# How to convert into array in this condition?

Tags: laravel

In Student model, i have made attribute like this

```
protected $appends = ['present'];

   public function getPresentAttribute(){
      return $this->getTotalDays()-$this->getAbsentDays();
   }
```

My Database looke like this

```
| id | student_name         |     created_at    |
*----*----------------------*-------------------*-- 
| 1  |  Adam                |     2020/11/10    | 
| 2  |  Annie               |     2020/11/10    |
|3   |  Paul                |     2020/11/10    |
```

if i do  like this in controller then

```
  $students=Student::get();
  foreach($students as $stu){
   echo "<pre>"; print_4($stu->student_name,$stu->present); die;
  }
```

My result will be like this

```
 Adam -> 32
 Annie ->34
 Paul->33
```

But i need to convert like this

```
 ['Students', 'Present Day',],
    ['Adam'     , 32],
    ['Annie'    , 34],
    ['Paul'     , 33],
```

So in controller, I tried like this

```
public function attendancePerformance(){
   $students=Student::get();
   $data=[];
   $student_data=[];
   $arrayHeader = ["Students","Present Day"];
   array_push($data,$arrayHeader);
       foreach ($students as $stu) {
            array_push($student_data, $stu->student_name,$stu->present);
         }
       array_push($data,$student_data)
    
   }
```

But it not working.How should i do it ?

Comment: Does it solve your issue  `$students = Student::get()->toArray();` ?

Comment: I donot think so because i need to send exact this  array in API so.

Comment: I append my header
and there are so many column in students table which i donot needso

Comment: where does `getTotalDays` and `getAbsentDays` get their data from?